# Orthogonal complement of $span(M)$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $M$ be a non-empty subset of a Euclidean space $V$. How would I prove this:

$(span\ M)^\bot=M^\bot$

Comment: It would bee good to know what you have already tried and what your doubts are.

Comment: I don't exactly know how to picture the $\bot$

Comment: Do you know the definition of orthogonal complement of a subspace?

Comment: Just wondering if you're struggling with the definition per se or with its geometrical interpretation.

Comment: Well, actually it's both. In the Definition, what does $\langle u,v\rangle =0$ mean, and also how would I interpret it geometrically?

Comment: I mean the angular brackets

Comment: It's the internal product between $u$ and $v$. The internal product is the generalization of the scalar product which is used in analytical geometry in spaces $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. Scalar product is the usual internal product.

Comment: I mean inner product. I'm sorry, English is not my mother language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\in {\rm span}\ M$ then $$ x= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i,\ m_i\in M $$

$({\rm span}\ M)^\perp \supset M^\perp $ : Hence for $v\in M^\perp$,
then
$$ x\cdot v= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i\cdot v =0 $$

That is, $$v\in ({\rm span}\ M)^\perp $$

$({\rm span}\ M)^\perp \subset M^\perp $ : Let $ v\in {\rm span}\
(M)^\perp $ so that
$$ x\cdot v= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i m_i\cdot v =0 $$

Since $x\neq 0$ then we can assume that $a_1=0$. By definition of
$v$, since $x-a_1m_1\in {\rm span }\ (M)$, then $$ (x-a_1 m_1)\cdot
v= 0
$$

This implies that $$ a_1m_1\cdot v =0 $$

Since $m_1$ is an arbitrary element in $M$, then $v\in M^\perp $.

Comment: You are assuming M finite. Can this be done without this hypotesis?

Answer (score 0):

To show two sets $A, B$ are equal you need to show whenever $x \in A \implies x \in B$ and whenever $x \in B \implies x \in A$.

Now suppose $x \in M^\perp$. Then by definition this means $\langle x, y \rangle = 0  \, \,   \forall \, \,  y \in M$.

On the other hand, if $x \in (\text{span } M)^\perp$ then similarly $x$ is orthogonal to every element in $\text{span } M$. In other words, if $M = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, \ldots\}$  then $$\langle x, a_1v_1+ a_2v_2 + a_3v_3 \ldots \rangle = 0  $$

In particular, see what happens when the coefficients are all one? Can you finish from here?